# how to make a resuable component with react-hook and yup?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, yup

Bellow my code:

https://github.com/robokonk/react-hook-component/blob/main/pages/index.tsx

I want to make a reusable component for input with validation, how I should correct it?
At the moment I have a problem with the pass register from react-hook as props to a component:
https://github.com/robokonk/react-hook-component/blob/main/components/input.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that does exactly that. Combine react-form-hook, yup and Material UI.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/jmaister/octo-form/

I created a React context to pass the data to the children components.

```
export const OctoFormContext = createContext({} as FormRenderContext<any>);

...

const renderProps : FormRenderContext<InferredType> = {
  control,
  schema,
  watch,
  editable,
}

...

return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <OctoFormContext.Provider value={renderProps}>
    {children}
  </OctoFormContext.Provider>
</form>;
```

In your case, you can pass the `register` function or whatever object that you need inside the rendreProps.

Take a look at the main component https://github.com/jmaister/octo-form/blob/master/src/OctoForm.tsx and to the most straightforward example inside the components folder: https://github.com/jmaister/octo-form/blob/master/src/components/FormInputText.tsx

Feel free to open issues with more specific questions in the GitHub project.